# How a finite extension of transcendence degree $1$ extensions induces a morphism of curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, schemes, valuation-theory, dedekind-domain

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. Throughout, by *curve* I mean integral, nonsingular, dimension $1$ scheme proper over $k$. In particular I'm assuming we're dealing with complete curves in the scheme theoretic sense. For a curve $X$, denote by $k(X)$ the function field which is a finitely-generated transcendence degree $1$ extension of $k$.

For a pair of finitely-generated transcendence degree $1$ extensions $K$ and $L$ of $k$, we must have that the extension $L / K$ is finite. I would like to use this to construct a morphism of curves. Assume for the time being that every such extension corresponds to a curve so I'm only concerned with constructing the actual morphism. I'm wondering if someone can point me in the right direction since I am fairly stuck at the moment. Here's what I've done so far, which is mostly what I've managed to piece together from Hartshorne I.6 and II.4,6:

Say $K(Y) \subseteq K(X)$ is a finite extension of fields of functions of curves $X$ and $Y$ respectively. Since these are proper. For a point $p \in X$ the local ring $\mathcal{O}_{X, p}$ is a DVR for a discrete valuation on $K(X)$ and the intersection $\mathcal{O}_{X, p} \cap K(Y)$ is a DVR for a discrete valuation on $K(X)$. Using the valuative criterion for properness, I have determined that $\mathcal{O}_{X, p} \cap K(Y)$ must dominate precisely one local ring for a closed point on $Y$, say $\mathcal{O}_{Y, q}$. Since valuation rings are characterised by the property of being maximal with respect to the relation of domination, we have that
$$
\mathcal{O}_{X, p} \cap K(Y) = \mathcal{O}_{Y, q}
$$
I would like my morphism $f: X \longrightarrow Y$ to be defined by the assignment $f(p) = q$. Is this the correct morphism?

I'm fairly confident this is the morphism I want to construct, so I would like to first show it is continuous. This is where I hit my first major problem. So to do this let $V = \text{spec } B$ be an affine open set in $Y$. Since $B$ must have Krull dimension $1$ and is an integral domain, it must be that every non-zero prime is maximal, and so every localization is a DVR since it corresponds to a closed point in the curve $Y$. So $B$ is a Dedekind domain. I'd like to show that the following set is open,
$$
f^{-1}(\text{spec } B) = \{  p \in X : \mathcal{O}_{X, p} \cap K(Y) = B_{\mathfrak{q}} \text{ for some prime ideal } \mathfrak{q} \subseteq B    \}.
$$
From what I've found online, this should be given by the spectrum of the integral closure of $B$ in $K(X)$, but I haven't been able to show this. Hartshorne claims it is "clear". But so far I haven't even been able to show it is open. I suspect that it will have something to do with the result from commutative algebra that says that since $B$ is an integrally closed noetherian domain (indeed it is a Dedekind domain) that it is equal to the intersection of the localisations at all prime ideals of height $1$ taken in $K(Y)$. Is anyone able to point me in the right direction? Ideally a suggestion on how to show that the set is open, or even better how to show it's actually the spectrum of the integral closure of $B$ in $K(X)$.

Comment: Well, $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}\cap K(Y)=B_\mathfrak{q}$ if and only if $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}$ is a DVR in $K(X)$ containing B. As you said, the intersection is a DVR of $K(Y)$, and it contains B precisely if it corresponds to a closed point of $\mathrm{Spec}\ B$. Now, we know that the preimage is normal, so that its coordinate ring is the intersection of all its local rings (as they are the codimension localizations, in this case). But as we've seen, these local rings as the DVRs in $K(X)$ that contain $B$, and so their intersection is the integral closure of $B$ in $K(X)$ (cf. Hartshorne 4.11A).

Comment: @ArturAraujo Thank you for the reply. This does clear up some things, although I am still not sure I understand why the first sentence of what you wrote is true. Why does $\mathcal{O}_{X, p}$ being a DVR in $K(X)$ containing $B$ imply that $\mathcal{O}_{X, p} \cap K(Y) = B_{\mathfrak{q}}$?

Comment: If a DVR R in $K(Y)$ contains B, then the intersection of the maximal ideal of R with B, $\mathfrak{m}\cap B$, is a maximal ideal $\mathfrak{n}$ of B. But then, $B_\mathfrak{n}\subset R$, and as you said, DVRs are maximal in this situation, so $B_\mathfrak{n}=R$.